# Create a custom magic in a Glue Studio Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, aws-glue, ipython-magic, spark-notebook

I've been trying to create custom magic for a Glue Studio Notebook, like the following example (taken from [here](https://ipython-books.github.io/14-creating-an-ipython-extension-with-custom-magic-commands/))

I've adding the Ipython module by running the glue magic

```
%additional_python_modules IPython
```

And running this from a cell:

```
from IPython.core.magic import (register_line_magic,
                                register_cell_magic)

@register_line_magic
def hello(line):
    if line == 'french':
        print("Salut tout le monde!")
    else:
        print("Hello world!")
```

However, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'register_magic_function'
```

Thanks.

I think is related to the fact that if i do

```
from IPython import get_ipython

get_ipython()
```

get_ipython() returns None.

This means that this is not running inside IPython, but what then? How can I add a custom magic? My goal is to have a magic to run sql queries in a postgresql database connected using a glue connection.